# CVS appends a ,v at end of file

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, cvs

I am using eclipse Luna with CVS for its synchronization and committing. However I keep getting a weird outcome from using it. For example my java class and file is named PrimeSieve. So when I commit the change, the file goes from being called PrimeSieve.java to PrimeSieve.java,v (the ,v gets appended). I don't quite understand or know where to get the resources to get the information to fix this. The reason I am trying to fix this is because when I run javac the ,v at the end gives me a bad flag warning with the compiler. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you using CVS in 2014?

Comment: Exactly what I asked my professor. Its a requirement for the class =\

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2267966/650012) SO question, it might have the answers you need.

Comment: People need to get over the fact that sometimes CVS is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CVS at the end of each file it appends a `,v` because that is indication of the type of file it is. Any file with a ,v at the end of it is a history file.

For you to be able to make use of the .java class you would have to checkout the history file like so:

```
co yourJavaFile.java,v
```

This leaves you with

```
yourJavaFile.java
```

Hopefully this helps someone.